# Arbitrary byte value in struct.pack()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, struct

I am trying to understand how struct work?

I have two confusions :

how struct is different from * and ** or *args and **kwargs ? where should i use struct and where should i use * and ** ?

My code is :

```
 list(b'stackoverflow')
[115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119]
```

second doubt is suppose if someone send me this code :

```
 [115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119]
```

i have to read it after unpacking it so general way is :

```
>>> struct.pack(b'bbbbbbbbbbbbb',115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119)
```

but i suppose i sentence is too long and i don't want to add many "bbbbbb" as argument so how can i use something which automatically detect the length of sentence ? something like

```
struct.pack(b'*magic',115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119)
```

can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `struct` module has nothing to do with argument passing, so I simply can't guess what you're asking about in the first part.

To your second question, you shouldn't be using `struct` at all for that purpose.  What you want is a `bytes` object corresponding to the list of little integers, and that's very easy to get:

```
>>> somelist = [115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119]
>>> bytes(somelist)
b'stackoverflow'
```

If for some reason you're determined to use `struct.pack` instead for this purpose, then this is the easiest way:

```
>>> struct.pack("b" * len(somelist), *somelist)
b'stackoverflow'
```

Comment: I meant * and ** also use for packing and unpacking then where struct pack and unpack uses ?

Comment: Can only repeat the two have nothing to do with each other.  You're only going to confuse yourself by imagining they do ;-)  `struct` is about stuffing data into low-level machine representations; argument passing gimmicks are at a vastly higher level.

Comment: i tried this and i thought i was actually looking like this but you make it more easy "struct.pack("b" * len(somelist) , 111, 112, 97, 115)"

Comment: sir can you recommend which is best for understanding deep about function programming?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "function programming" means - but Stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask for general advice anyway.  If you can flesh out what you mean, try asking on the Python mailing list?  https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list

Comment: @sir i meant functional programming :) my badluck

Comment: Same answer ;-)  This isn't the right place to ask for general advice.  If functional programming is your passion, then you're best off using a functional language (say, Haskell).  If you want to explore functional programming in Python, get familiar with the `operator` and `itertools` modules and start a discussion on the general Python mailing list (same as the Usenet group comp.lang.python).

Comment: @sir made my day for replying here ;) Thanks

Comment: @sir last question have you written any book on python or blog on python ?

Comment: Nope!  I'm too old for that stuff - computers confuse me ;-)  Good luck! :-)